# Ng Build an Angular 7 Project in IntelliJ Webstorm or IDEA

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, webstorm, angular7

How do I build an Angular CLI project in IntelliJ IDEA or Webstorm? I want an option to run `ng build` command for my Angular 7 Project, instead of running it through the command prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run `ng build`, open your `package.json` in IDEA (WebStorm) editor and press the run icon in the gutter to the left of the `'build"` script:

[image]

To run `ng serve`, run `"start"` script.
Note that the IDE auto-creates the **Angular CLI Server** run configuration for running `ng serve`, you can use it to start the app.

See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/ - you may find this blog post helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you open up Webstorm and have alook at the top right hand side of the page you will find a dropdown saying, `Angular CLI Server`. Click on the dropdown and click on `Edit Configuration`.

Once you have done the above you are going to end up at this window[image].

Once you have that window open change the `Scripts` to `build`. Once you have done that you can run the Angular application normally with the green Run button at the top right of your screen

Comment: thanks, this is awesome, I will give points, is this what people normally do? I didn't see a lot of resources on this

Comment: This is how I normally do it, I am not sure about other people to be honest with you.

Comment: rather than modifying the pre-created run configuration, you can create a new configuration for `build` - see my answer above. WebStorm provides 3 ways to start NPM scripts: from package.json gutter, from **NPM** tool window (can be opened via package.json right-click menu) or by creating a new **NPM** run configuration manually in **Run | Edit configurations...**