# Intellij Idea configure two commands to dpeloy Angular project

Tags: intellij-idea, angular-cli

It is about Angular project. Is there a way to configure in Intellij Idea run configuration to execute two commands one after another like:

1. ng build --prod,
2. firebase deploy.

Now every time I deploy I need to write all that manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `package.json`, add [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts) that run your commands, like:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy"
  }
```

Now you will be able to run both commands from the editor gutter

[image]

Once you do this, the IDE will auto-create the run configurations for you. You can either run them one after another manually, or add the `build` run configuration to the [Before launch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/run-debug-configuration-npm.html#before-launch-options) section of the `deploy` one in the [Edit configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) dialog

Answer (score 0):

In the right corner next to run-Button you see your a Dropdown-Button.
There you can Edit your configurations.
Now a new window will open where you will see the configurations.
In the left corner you will see a + sign.
Click on it and add the config you need.

Comment: The problem is where and how exactly to add this config.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721508/ng-build-an-angular-7-project-in-intellij-webstorm-or-idea